# Fatal error: Class 'CakeSession' not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I tried to change local webserver to online CakePHP can not works.

> Fatal error: Class 'CakeSession' not found in
>   /usr/local/www/htdocs/koyakei/public_html/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php on
>   line 147

so changed this file on line 147 `cakeroot/index,php`　to this:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cake-php/3g8J3BwSElA/4vt3C15b4sIJ

But, same error appears.

Cake is plane cake not configured. 2.44.  In local it is working.

`/tmp`:

*Owner*:       **Read** ok   **Write** ok **Execute** no

*Group*:       **Read** ok   **Write** ok **Execute** no

*Everyone*:  **Read** ok   **Write** ok **Execute** no

666 All sub files and directories tmp must executable?

Comment: might be file permissions issue.

Comment: / tmp 

Owner: Read ok Write  ok Execute no
Group: Read ok Write ok Execute no
Everyone: Read ok  Write  okExecute no
666 all sub files and directories tmp
 Must executable?

Comment: Have you tries  App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
                $user_id = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');

Comment: I added that code to app/Config/bootstrap　index each app/controller but not works.

Comment: did you add Session component to your controller?
`public $components = array('Session');`

Answer (score 2):

Just put

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
```

on top of the file

Answer (score 0):

Check your core.php file

Check that you have:

```html
<?php

Configure::write('Session', array(
  'defaults' => 'cake'
 ));

?>
```

Make sure you have the directory "sessions" in your tmp folder: /app/tmp/sessions

If you do not have the "sessions" directory, add it.

If you do have it, I suggest you remove all files with in the directory and see if that solves your issue.

Make sure chmod 766 for tmp folder recursive.

Lastly, make sure you are initiating the CakeSession.